# The question page's bounty section still looks sketchy

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

Comment: fixing is on the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the fix in. Please verify.

Comment: Only the text box is orange, the actual bounty box is still red

Comment: It looks much better, thanks! I'm not in love with the box being orange, but I don't have any better ideas.

Comment: i'm sure i'll go through the entire site later and improve the details. same for other SE graduates too! a lot to do ATM.

Answer (score 3):

The ["bounty-awarded" icon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/how-do-i-earn-sc2s-hurry-up-its-raid-night-achievement) is pretty fugly too, not sure if that's from the old design or not.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bounty box shouldn't be red. I think the red clashes with the site and doesn't mesh well with the overall theme. Perhaps purple instead of red for a start?

Comment: Green fits in better tbh

Comment: green is normal associated with accepted answers. i think i'll use orange instead.

Comment: I think the color should be "red dominated" This would keep it inline with other stack exchanges but minimize clashing.